# How to bind a delete method to a rendered web component

Tags: javascript, shopify, native-web-component

I am having trouble figuring out how to bind my handleDelete method.

The way I have it structured is the user clicks the plus button then data objects get stored in an array on the window object. Then render is called on the SelectedProducts component that renders a card that has the button I am trying to bind the handleDelete method to.

If you run the code you can see what I have so far.

Maybe this is not the right approach just trying to do it with out adding a library.

Still trying to wrap my head around which lifecycle methods I need or a custom event?

```js
class SelectedProducts extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.mockData = [
      { id: 1, name: 'name-1', qty: 1 },
      { id: 2, name: 'name-2', qty: 1 },
      { id: 2, name: 'name-1', qty: 2 },
    ];
  }
  handleDelete(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('called handleDelete');
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', this.handleDelete.bind(this));
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldValue, newValue) {
    console.log('attributeChange called');
    this.handleDelete(e);
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['data-id'];
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {
    console.log('disconnectedCallback ran');
  }

  render() {
    this.mockData.forEach((item, index) => {
      this.innerHTML += `
      <div style="display:flex; align-items: center; background-color:white; padding:15px; ">
        <button data-id="${item.id}" class="delete-btn">
          Delete me
        </button>
      </div>
      `;
    });
  }

  handleDelete(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Called Handle delete');
  }
}
customElements.define('selected-products', SelectedProducts);

class ProductCard extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open',
    });

    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML =
      `<style>
      ::slotted(div){
        color: #4B5563; 
        font-weight: 900; 
        text-align: center; 
        font-size: 20px; 
      }
      </style>
      ` +
      ` <div style="background: white; margin-right: 15px;">
          <slot name="button"></slot>
          <slot name="img"></slot>
        </div>
      `;
  }
}

customElements.define('product-card', ProductCard);

class SelectBtn extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // This is called with render below
    this.itemsPicked = document.querySelector('selected-products');
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open',
    });
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
    <button
    aria-label="Select"
    type="button"
    class="pressed"
    data-addbtn="add-btn"
  >
   +
  </button>
    
    `;

    this.id = this.getAttribute('id');
    this.name = this.getAttribute('name');
    this.shadowRoot
      .querySelectorAll('button')
      .forEach((button) => button.addEventListener('click', this.handleSelect.bind(this)));
  }
  // Get data from attributes & store object in
  // an array on window object
  handleSelect(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.itemsPicked.render();
  }
}

customElements.define('select-button', SelectBtn);
```

```html
<body>
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: lightblue; padding: 10px">
      <product-card>
        <div slot="button">
          <select-button id="1" name="product name"></select-button>
        </div>
        <div slot="img">
          <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px">Select Button</div>
        </div>
      </product-card>
      <div>
        <selected-products></selected-products>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.selectedItems = {
        items: [],
      };
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: I would start with some basic web component tutorials, it looks like you're kind of guessing how web components work. Read about the difference between `connectedCallback` and `constructor`.

Comment: I do have some understanding of lifecycle methods and how the constructor works. I will visit again the docs again.

Comment: @AndyRay Question since the innerHtml is not initialized in the constructor would it be better to attach an event listener in the connectedCallback since this is available after the component is mounted.  Is it even possible to attach an event listener to the innerHTML in this case?

Comment: When you add Minimal code it is easier for us to understand.  80% of your code above is not related to your question. And don't be surprised; 80% of the time you will solve your own problem when you create Minimal code. HTH

Comment: Danny I refactored the question and removed as much unnecessary code and still be able to run snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this problem was not to attach an event listener to inner html itself. Instead I created another web component (delete-button) with and event listener and a method to handle the event. Any feedback would be super cool.

```js
class DeleteButton extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.selectedProducts = document.querySelector('selected-products');
    this.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((button) => button.addEventListener('click', this.handleDelete.bind(this)));
  }

  handleDelete(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Delete button Event');
  }
}
customElements.define('delete-button', DeleteButton);

class SelectedProducts extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.mockData = [
      { id: 1, name: 'name-1', qty: 1 },
      { id: 2, name: 'name-2', qty: 1 },
      { id: 2, name: 'name-1', qty: 2 },
    ];
  }

  render() {
    this.mockData.forEach((item, index) => {
      this.innerHTML += `
      <div style="display:flex; align-items: center; background-color:white; padding:15px; ">
        <delete-button>
          <button data-id="${item.id}" class="delete-btn">
            Delete me
          </button>
        </delete-button>
      </div>
      `;
    });
  }

  handleDelete(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Called Handle delete');
  }
}
customElements.define('selected-products', SelectedProducts);

class ProductCard extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open',
    });

    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML =
      `<style>
      ::slotted(div){
        color: #4B5563; 
        font-weight: 900; 
        text-align: center; 
        font-size: 20px; 
      }
      </style>
      ` +
      ` <div style="background: white; margin-right: 15px;">
          <slot name="button"></slot>
          <slot name="img"></slot>
        </div>
      `;
  }
}

customElements.define('product-card', ProductCard);

class SelectBtn extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // This is called with render below
    this.itemsPicked = document.querySelector('selected-products');
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open',
    });
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
    <button
    aria-label="Select"
    type="button"
    class="pressed"
    data-addbtn="add-btn"
  >
   +
  </button>
    
    `;

    this.id = this.getAttribute('id');
    this.name = this.getAttribute('name');
    this.shadowRoot
      .querySelectorAll('button')
      .forEach((button) => button.addEventListener('click', this.handleSelect.bind(this)));
  }
  // Get data from attributes & store object in
  // an array on window object
  handleSelect(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.itemsPicked.render();
  }
}

customElements.define('select-button', SelectBtn);
```

```html
<body>
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: lightblue; padding: 10px">
      <product-card>
        <div slot="button">
          <select-button id="1" name="product name"></select-button>
        </div>
        <div slot="img">
          <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px">Select Button</div>
        </div>
      </product-card>
      <div>
        <selected-products></selected-products>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.selectedItems = {
        items: [],
      };
    </script>
  </body>
```